C++20 modules and PIMPL idiom
I am struggling with PIMPL idiom with C++20 modules. I am using some 3rd party library, which I don't want expose to the library user. I created following gist to show necessary files: https://gist.github.com/mickes27/524e57c7fa95ac221be0b5ea8a9f4003. I am using CMake, CMakeLists.txt is included. I found several problems:

I cannot name InternalPartition.ixx, because I got error C7622: module interface file extension is incompatible with '/module:internalPartition' as the partition is not an interface. I assume this is some MSVC internal stuff, that only interface modules (the one with export keyword can have .ixx extension).

When I am importing InternalPartition in MyLibrary.cpp (module implementation unit), I got error MyLibrary.cpp(12): error C2027: use of undefined type 'lib::Internal'. I assumed (probably incorrectly) that class declared in primary module interface unit and the one defined in internal partition are the same and should be visible (after importing).

When I try to get rid of forward declare and import InternalPartition right in MyLibrary.ixx, I got: CMake error : Public C++ module source MyLibrary.ixx requires the MyLibrary:InternalPartition C++ module which is provided by a private source - but I don't want to make internal partition part of public module, what would be the point of it being internal then?

If I try to get rid of internal partition stuff at all and treat InternalPartition.cpp  as module implementation file (module MyLibrary; instead of module MyLibrary:InternalPartition;), we get back to pt. 2 - Internal is not specified anywhere (doesn't matter if I forward declare it in MyLibrary.ixx or not).


Does anybody has an idea how can I use PIMPL idiom + C++20 modules without need to declare Internal class directly inside MyLibrary.cpp?

You're writing a library as a module, which uses a 3rd-party library, and you don't want to expose that 3rd party library's interface ? I don't much about modules, but in cmake, you would just target_link_libraries(lib PRIVATE 3rd_party) and that's it. After any necessary find_package callls and all that.

@sweenish, Isn't that a bad design to just put 3rd party stuff directly into public interface? If I do that, I will not create stable API (leaking internal implementstions details), right?

As yet, I can only make this work by defining class Internal directly inside MyLibrary.cpp. That keeps it away from clients that import module MyLibrary, but does not answer your question! Along the way, I did notice that you are missing the constructor for class MyLibrary that should initialize member internal. Declare it in MyLibrary.ixx, and define it in MyLibrary.cpp, alongside MyLibrary::foo.

Yes, that's true. I wanted to keep code as minimal and since it does not influence compilation, I omitted it.

My suggestion doesn’t put the 3rd party interface in your library’s. The all caps PRIVATE is the clue there.

I mean, if the 3rd party library is in module interface unit, wouldn't I need this library to create BMI, when somebody consume it? I am not sure how CMake will treat that, what about interface transitive properties?

In InternalPartition.cpp (that should be .ixx I guess), you must export your partition, and export the definiton of Internal, so when MyLibrary.cpp import it, it has access to the exported class.
export module MyLibrary:InternalPartition;
...
export class Internal
...


That wouldn't be internal partition after that, it would be module interface unit as it contributes to interface.
